# Double click an element using Selenium Webdriver - Facebook PHP library

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to double click an dom element using Selenium Webdriver - Facebook PHP library.

There's no direct way to perform a double click on the element, but there's a way over `WebDriverMouse` this is how far I've got.

```
$myElement = $myWebDriver->findElement(WebDriverBy::id('myElement'));
$myWebDriver->getMouse()->doubleClick($myElement->getLocation());
```

Unfortunately this isn't working since `->getLocation` returns an instance of `WebDriverPoint` but the method `->doubleClick()` needs an instance of `WebDriverCoordinates`.

Is there an easier way to perform the double click or is there a way do create a `WebDriverCoordinates` instance out of a `WebDriverPoint` object?

Thank you very much for you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternative using the action builder.

```
$myElement = $myWebDriver->findElement(WebDriverBy::id('myElement'));
$driver->actions()->doubleClick()->perform();
```

Also, `$driver->actions()` allows action chain / composite actions.

Drag and Drop example:

```
$driver->actions()->mouseDown($source)
                  ->mouseMove($target)
                  ->mouseUp($target);
                  ->perform();
```

But actually, you can do drag and drop by just one method.

```
$driver->actions()->dragAndDrop($source, $target)->perform();
```

Comment: On the version of the facebook bindings I use, I need to do $driver->action() (without the "s"). But this is great, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Sorry, was to fast with the question. Just figured it out:

```
$myElement = $myWebDriver->findElement(WebDriverBy::id('myElement'));
$myWebDriver->getMouse()->doubleClick($myElement->getCoordinates());
```